# RHEL Terminal Prompt is "unknown"

Tags: linux, rhel

In my RHEL 7, my terminal prompt changes from *localhost* to *UNKNOWN* when I connect to the Internet. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What you see at the prompt at the terminal is a name assigned by your DHCP Server appended by your MAC Address.
  Try to search for **dhclient.conf** might be in **/etc/dhcp**

Edit the request statement and remove the `host-name` out of the list.
It should be like this

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers
```